# How to make a request wait for a previous request to complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, asynchronous

I am trying to send API calls to a NodeJS server. Unfortunately, the server (that was not made by me) won't allow me to make async calls.

I am trying to figure out a way to make every request to wait for the previous request to finish before being sent.

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

// An object of options to indicate where to post to
var post_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8080',
    path: '/api/scan',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};
var array = ["ssl.com", "google.com", "hamzakhan.org"];
for (var i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
    //console.log(array[i]);
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            // Make sure it's working
            console.log(body.response.subject);
        });
    });

    var url = array[i];
    var catURL = { "url": url, "path": "/", "port": "443", "live_scan": "false", "advanced": "true" };
    post_req.write(JSON.stringify(catURL), function(err) {
        //console.log(err);
        post_req.end();
    });

}
```

I was thinking I could nest a while loop inside the for loop, and the while loop would have a flag that would dictate when the for loop could keep going.

Now, this code works when I hardcode the value of `url` as a single url, so i know that I am successful in sending and receiving.

Thanks for all/any help!

Comment: Instead of looping through your `array` variable, you could, for instance, start with its first element, then put a callback inside your `res.on('end',function() { ... /* callback here */ ... })` to tell your program to start a new request each time a response ends, until there are no more requests to be sent. What do you think?

Comment: How do i start a new request?

Comment: Please see example based on your code below. Note that I did not test that example. I simply added a few lines in order to illustrate my suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Disclaimer: I did not test your code. I simply added a few
 * lines to illustrate my suggestion.
 */

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

// An object of options to indicate where to post to

var post_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8080',
    path: '/api/scan',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

var array = ["ssl.com", "google.com", "hamzakhan.org"];
var emitter = new EventEmitter();
var counter = 0, n = array.length;

function PostRequest() {
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            // Make sure it's working
            console.log(body.response.subject);

            // ADD THE CALLBACK 
            // OR 
            // TRIGGER EVENT
            return emitter.emit('ResponseEnded');

        });
    });

    var url = array[counter];
    var catURL = { "url": url, "path": "/", "port": "443", "live_scan": "false", "advanced": "true" };
    post_req.write(JSON.stringify(catURL), function(err) {
        //console.log(err);
        post_req.end();
    });
}

emitter.on('ResponseEnded',function() {
    ++counter;
    if (counter < n) {
        PostRequest();
    }
    else {
        console.log('Nothing more request');
    }
});

// Start with the first request
PostRequest();
```

Update: This is another way of doing the same thing.

```
/**
 * Disclaimer: I did not test your code. I simply added a few
 * lines to illustrate my suggestion.
 */

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');


// An object of options to indicate where to post to

var post_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8080',
    path: '/api/scan',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

var array = ["ssl.com", "google.com", "hamzakhan.org"];
var counter = 0, n = array.length;

function PostRequest() {
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            // Make sure it's working
            console.log(body.response.subject);

            // THIS IS ANOTHER WAY OF DOING IT
            ++counter;
            if (counter < n) {
                /**
                 * This is were your start new 
                 * requests
                 */
                PostRequest();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Nothing more request');
            }            

        });
    });

    var url = array[counter];
    var catURL = { "url": url, "path": "/", "port": "443", "live_scan": "false", "advanced": "true" };
    post_req.write(JSON.stringify(catURL), function(err) {
        //console.log(err);
        post_req.end();
    });
}

// Start with the first request
PostRequest();
```

Comment: In this case, what are you referring to as my callback? I'm sorry, i'm pretty new to this.

Comment: A callback is a function that you call once a task has been completed. In this case, I used an event emitter to make it clearer that we were waiting for a response to end before submitting another request; i.e. when the request ends, I am emitting an event called 'ResponseEnded', and I have an event listener listing for that event at the bottom.

Comment: Nevermind. It worked. For some reason i had somehow switched `counter < n` to `counter > n`